# how to show wildcard subdomain content based on url by .htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

If the user enters `example.domain.com`, I want him to see what's in `www.domain.com/example`.

Another example:

User will request 
`example.domain.com/photos/gallery.php?from=var1&no=3`, 
he'll see what's in `www.domain.com/example/photos/gallery.php?from=var&no=3`.

Note: in my subfolders(wildcards) I will have WordPress installed so I have to keep in mind that URL system as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assuming that you have already configured the wildcard subdomain in your DNS and your server config is configured to accept such requests. So that these subdomains all resolve to the root directory of your main domain.

I'm also assuming that you want to keep the subdomain in the browser's address bar.

You can then do something like the following in the `.htaccess` file in the document root:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^ /%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

This excludes the www subdomain from being rewritten.

Providing the subdirectory has its own `.htaccess` file with mod_rewrite directives (as you would expect with WordPress) then there should be nothing else you need to do.

---

**UPDATE:** However, if you *don't have WordPress installed* in the subdirectory, ie. you don't have a `.htaccess` containing mod_rewrite directives in the subdirectory, then you will need to modify the above code, by adding an additional condition, to prevent a rewrite loop (500 Internal Server Error).

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^ /%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

The condition that checks against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable prevents a rewrite loop by blocking rewritten requests. However, as noted above, this is unnecessary if WordPress is already installed in the subdirectory.

Comment: Where should I put it on every sub-directory or only the wildcard root directory?

Comment: As stated, "in the `.htaccess` file in the document root". There is presumably a common document root for the main domain and all subdomains?

Comment: Its redirecting me an endless loop. Have a look http://shop.getoxizen.shop

Comment: Is WordPress installed in the subdirectory?

Comment: no it has a index.php file

Comment: (I've just updated the code - it should be a rewrite, not a redirect.) This code is under the assumption that you have WordPress installed in the subdirectory (as stated in the question). This would prevent a "rewrite loop".

Comment: Now it showing ''Internal Server Error" plz check the link

Comment: The 500 error is the result of a rewrite loop. Yes, that is correct - you said you had WordPress installed in the subdirectory. That is what my answer is based on. If you don't have WordPress installed then you will need to add an additional condition to prevent a loop. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Now its showing not found even there are more then 2 folder. here is my directory-http://prntscr.com/lyzvq9

Comment: What file(s) do you have in the `shop` and `shop2` subdirectories?

Comment: In shop I have WordPress installed and shop2 it has normal index.php file

Comment: http://getoxizen.shop/shop2/index.php its working here

Comment: This does appear to work OK... `http://shop2.getoxizen.shop/` and `http://shop2.getoxizen.shop/index.php` both work as expected, returning the content from `http://getoxizen.shop/shop2/index.php`. (?)

Comment: BTW can I set a custom 404 page by .htaccess when the subdomain will not be there one more thing I would like to skip the www part form the url

Comment: You mean when the "subdirectory" does not exist (that the subdomain should map to). You could just create a custom 404, such as `ErrorDocument 404 /e404.php` that would be triggered for such requests. However, this will also catch 404s for subdomains that don't define their own custom 404 or are not driven by a CMS such as WordPress. But still, this would be my preferred method. You can then check in this 404 document for the reason for the 404 (ie. whether the root directory exists or not).

Comment: "I would like to skip the www part form the url" - what do you mean? This should should already ignore requests for any www subdomain.

Comment: Now problem is when I go to install WordPress http://shop.getoxizen.shop/ it says 404 not found

Comment: even when wodpress got installed its url create based on main url like http://getoxizen.shop/shop/example/exmpl2 this way so in first place this .htaccess just showing the front page according to my wish but its not covering my other part "User will request example.domain.com/photos/gallery.php?from=var1&no=3, he'll see what's in www.domain.com/example/photos/gallery.php?from=var&no=3"

Comment: These issues are probably caused by the WordPress config (not `.htaccess`). You need to make sure that the `WP_SITEURL` and `WP_HOME` constants are set appropriately. Whilst WordPress is installed in a subdirectory - that subdirectory is not part of the URL - WordPress needs to be made aware of this.